Spring data native with project get a proxy result
I use spring data jpa, for one query, i use native query
public interface EditorDto {

        Long getEditorId();
        String getName();
}


@Query(value = """
select e1_0.editor_Id as editorId,e1_0.name as name
 from
    process r1_0
    LEFT JOIN Deposit d ON R1_0.process_id= d.process_id
    LEFT JOIN Claim c ON d.deposit_id = r.deposit_id
    join Editor e1_0 on e1_0.editor_Id=r1_0.editor_Id
where
    and e1_0.code=:code
    AND r1_0.editor_Id =E1_0.editor_Id
""", nativeQuery = true)
List<EditorDto> findEditorProjection(String code);

when i check the result

There is something with
AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TuypeBackedMap
